# Java Session time out popup

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 and I have a requirement that when ever session time out is happening then i want show a Timeout warning popup and from the popup if i click Ok button from the Timeout warning window is clicked then the session want to continue other wise it should redirect to the session time out page could you please help me in this how to create this type of requirement.

Thanks, Mani

Answer (score 2):

Only from theory: Primefaces component library has a component [`p:idleMonitor`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/idleMonitor.jsf) where a popup dialog appears after a certain time:

```
<p:idleMonitor timeout="10000"   
            onidle="idleDialog.show()" onactive="idleDialog.hide()"/>
```

I never used it in practice but when I noticed this component, I thought this could be used as a session timeout warning system. Maybe you can adapt it for your special functional requirements. But keep in mind that this component counts client idle time and not server idle time.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your quick response i dont want to use primefaces i can use jquery or Ajax to implement this

Comment: Primefaces uses JQuery under the covers. Maybe the source code in the Primefaces showcase (the link in my answer) will guide you a little bit in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

i got solution
in java script i created all Jquery functions as public

```
 var defaults = {
        inactivity: 600000, //10 Minutes
        noconfirm: 300000, //5 minutes
        sessionAlive: 900000, //15 Minutes
        redirect_url: 'TimeOut.xhtml',
        click_reset: true,
        alive_url: '',
        logout_url: 'TimeOut.xhtml'
    }


var opts = $.extend(defaults);
var liveTimeout, confTimeout, sessionTimeout;

$(function(){
    start_liveTimeout = function() 
      {
        clearTimeout(liveTimeout);
        clearTimeout(confTimeout);
        liveTimeout = setTimeout(logout, opts.inactivity);

        if(opts.sessionAlive)
        {
          clearTimeout(sessionTimeout);
          sessionTimeout = setTimeout(keep_session, opts.sessionAlive);
        }
      };    
  });

$(function(){
    logout = function() {       
        confTimeout = setTimeout(redirect, opts.noconfirm);
        showAlert();        
      };    
  });

$(function(){
    redirect = function() {
        if(opts.logout_url)
        {
          $.get(opts.logout_url);
        }
        window.location.href = opts.redirect_url;
      };
  });

$(function(){
    stay_logged_in = function(el) {
        start_liveTimeout();
        if(opts.alive_url)
        {
          $.get(opts.alive_url);
        }
      };
  });

$(function(){
    keep_session = function() {
        $.get(opts.alive_url);
        clearTimeout(sessionTimeout);
        sessionTimeout = setTimeout(keep_session, opts.sessionAlive);
      } ;

  });

(function($){
    $.fn.idleTimeout = function(options) {

      return this.each(function() {
        obj = $(this);
        start_liveTimeout();
        if(opts.click_reset)
        {
          $(document).bind('click', start_liveTimeout);
        }
        if(opts.sessionAlive)
        {
          keep_session();
        }
      });

    };
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).idleTimeout();
    $("input[id$=btnOK]").click(function () {
        $.modal.close();
        stay_logged_in(); 
    });
});

function showAlert() {
    idleSessionAlert = $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        opacity : 50,
        overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"},
        escClose : false, 
        modal:true,     
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.slideDown('slow', function () {
                dialog.data.hide();
                dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        },
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
                    dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                    });
                });
            });
        }

    });
}
```

In Css

```
#basic-modal-content {
    display: none;
}
#simplemodal-container {
    display:none;
    height:300px; 
    width:530px; 
    color:#000000; 
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:12px;
}
#simplemodal-container p {
    color:#000000; 
    display:block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-style: verdana normal;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 510px;
}
.modalGroupHeader { 
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-style: arial normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 0.615em;
    padding-bottom: 0.615em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.modalSectionHeader {
    line-height: 48px;
    font-style: arial normal;
    font-size: 1.308em;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    color: #007dba;
    float: left;
    width: 530px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.modalSectionHeader_left {
    height: 48px;
    width: 15px;
    background-image: url(../images/sectionHeader/sectionHeader_left.gif);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.modalSectionHeader_right {
    right: 0;
    height: 48px;
    width: 15px;
    background-image: url(../images/sectionHeader/sectionHeader_right.gif);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
.modalSectionHeader_body {
    line-height: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 500px;
    background-image: url(../images/sectionHeader/sectionHeader_tile.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.modalButtonPanel { 
    width: 530px;
    float: left;
    bottom: 10px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

In my xhtml i am calling JSf ajax request in the button so it will extend my session

```
 <div id="basic-modal-content">
                <p>Click OK to continue your session</p>
                    <h:commandButton id="btnOK" styleClass="btnOK">
                        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{HandlerBean.extendSession()}" immediate="true" ></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
            </div>
```